# Wait for a query in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb

I have this async method written in Typescript to query, with the nodejs driver, a MongoDB; the compiler indicates that the "await" before "myConnectedClient" *has no effect on the type of this expression*; I'm confused: is the call to the aggregate() asynchronous? So, I have to wait, or not?
Thanks.

```
async findQuery<T>(
    collection: string,
    findParams: Query<T>,
    sort: Sort<T>,
    myConnectedClient: MongoClient
  ) {
    const firstResult = await myConnectedClient // the compiler indicates await is useless
      .db("ZZZ_TEST_ALL")
      .collection("my_collection_01")
      .aggregate<string>([{ $project: { _id: 0, name: 1 } }]);
    firstResult.forEach((field) => {
      console.log(`Field: ${field}`);
    });
  }
```

**UPDATE:** I have to add .toArray() after the .aggregate() call; but why? Can anybody explain me the mechanism? aggregate() has not callback and does not return a promise? Are there alternatives to .toArray()? Thanks.

```
// now await it's ok
const firstResult = await myConnectedClient
      .db("ZZZ_TEST_ALL")
      .collection("my_collection_01")
      .aggregate<string>([{ $project: { _id: 0, name: 1 } }]).toArray();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Aggregate](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.2/classes/Collection.html#aggregate) is sync and returns an [AggregationCursor](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.2/classes/AggregationCursor.html).

The cursor has number of async methods to retrieve actual data: [toArray](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.2/classes/AggregationCursor.html#toArray), [forEach](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.2/classes/AggregationCursor.html#toArray), or simple [iterator](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.2/classes/AggregationCursor.html#_asyncIterator_)

In the first snippet firstResult  is the cursor, so there is no need to await.
You use firstResult.forEach to log  the results. It does return the promise but you ignore it, which will bite you - the promise returned by findQuery will be resolved immediately while forEach will iterate results in parallel. To keep the promise chain you should do

```
const firstResult = myConnectedClient.......; 
return firstResult.forEach(......);
```

so the promise returned from the `findQuery` will be resolved only when forEach is resolved, e.g. you finish iterate the results.

In the second "update" snippet, the firstResult is the data, so you need the await to get it from toArray(). The equivalent with explicit cursor would be:

```
const cursor = myConnectedClient.......; 
const firstResult = await cursor.toArray();
```

Comment: But why aggregate() is not async? It's retrieves data from a db (I/O), so in my mind should be asynchronous, right?

Comment: Because the documentation says so. The very top line behind the first link in my answer says: `aggregate<T>(pipeline?: Document[], options?: AggregateOptions): AggregationCursor<T>` You see, it returns an object. Async functions always return a Promise. It's javascript.  Single thread, the only way to do something async is to give control back to the event loop.

Comment: I think you are confused by I/O operations with thin  clients, like file I/O, http, sql. Mongo is slightly different. The client is quite thick, it opens an number of persistent connections to mongo instances at start and manages the pool to facilitate data transfer. Aggregation retrieves no data but sends a request to run the pipeline on the server.  Cursor has a number of async methods to actually retrieve data, but I thin I mentioned it already in the answer.

Comment: I totally appreciate the attitude to understand everything  and build software based on this knowledge. It would be ideal. The fundamental flaw of this approach is that in the real world nobody knows everything. At some point you need to draw a line and just trust the documentation - if it says it works like that, tests show it does indeed, so it must be it.

Comment: Thanks Alex for taking the time to reply.